# how to verify a void method 'returned' in mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am testing a function which is of below structure:

```
void method1() {
   if(booleanCondition1) {
      return;
   }
   callMethod2();
   callMethod3();
...
..
   callMethod-n();
}
```

I have to write a mock test for this, when `booleanCondition1` evaluates to TRUE.
One way is make sure, `callMethod2()`, and `callMethod3()` and so on until `callMethod-n()` are never invoked(using `Mockito.never()`).

Is there any efficient way of doing this rather than making sure all the statements after return were not invoked?

In other words, can i verify if "return" statement was invoked using Mockito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't test which `return` statement was encountered, but you can do `verifyZeroInteractions` or `verifyNoMoreInteractions` to encompass a lot of `verify(mock, never())` assertions.

Use it sparingly--`verifyNoMoreInteractions` can lead to brittle tests if overused.

Comment: Hi Jeff, this would half of my problem . I also need to verify that some methods on Spied objects(not mocks) are not invoked.  Is there a similar method for spied targets also?

Comment: @venkataratnam Those calls--and most of the rest of Mockito--work on spies as well as mocks.

Comment: i tried this on a object constructed like this (Instance it  = spy(new Instance()), i got an error saying "not a mock"

Comment: What you describe is allowed in Mockito. Please make a reproducible example as a separate question, as this is growing outside the scope of this comment box.